# Jenkins/Groovy shell return type/equality

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the return value of a shell script in a Jenkinsfile as a way to branch logic.  However I don't understand what is being returned or why it isn't equal.

To reproduce the problem you could write this in a Jenkinsfile:

```
response = sh(script: "echo hello", returnStdout: true)
print response // hello is printed as expected 
print response == 'hello' // false
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `print response == 'hello\n'`

Comment: That was it Tim.  Thanks! I feel silly for not figuring that out.